# Sh: add all files from a folder to an array

Tags: unix, sh

I am trying to use an array to store all `.txt` files from a folder that have a name which do not contain the word, "silent". Until now, I tried the following commands, but with no success:

```
ACTIVE_LOGS=($(`find $DEST_DIR -name '*.txt'  '!' -name '*silent*'`))
ACTIVE_LOGS=($("find $DEST_DIR -name '*.txt'  '!' -name '*silent*'"))
```

I have to mention that the following command works as expected:

```
ACTIVE_LOGS=`find $DEST_DIR -name '*.txt'  '!' -name '*silent*'`
```

but I need an array instead of a variable.

Comment: What shell are you using? POSIX `sh` does not support arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring an array as a shell variable might require, depending of the shell you're using, the initial values to be separated by spaces (or tabs, I think). But the `find(1)` prints out results from your search separated by newlines. Using `-printf` instead of `-print` gives the result you're after:

```
ACTIVE_LOGS=($(find $DEST_DIR -name '*.txt'  '!' -name '*silent*' -printf "%f "))
```

The back quotes are also redundant as `$()` already produces a subshell.

With Bash arrays work as you expect even without fiddling with newlines:

```
ACTIVE_LOGS=($(find $DEST_DIR -name '*.txt'  '!' -name '*silent*'))
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any shell that requires specific types of whitespace to separate array elements.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you are adding an extra layer of quoting inside the command substitution; just remove them.

```
ACTIVE_LOGS=($(find "$DEST_DIR" -name '*.txt'  '!' -name '*silent*'))
```

In `bash` (and other shells; syntax may vary), you can dispense with `find` altogether.

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob extglob
ACTIVE_LOGS=( "$DESTDIR"/**/!(*silent*).txt )
```

`globstar` lets you use `**` to match zero or more directories; `nullglob` causes the pattern to disappear, rather than be treated literally, if there are no matches; and `extglob` lets you use `!(*silent*)` to match anything *but* the pattern `*silent*`.